# Decoding audio data using OPUS library but not getting clear voice and split arraybytes then convert to shortbyte in Objective-c iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, core-audio, short, opus

Iam trying to decoding audio data using OPUS library..
iam able to decode data but voice is not clear..Actually iam getting encoded audio data from voice translating device just i need to decode audio data and data length iam getting from device is 160..
Now i need convert to Bytearray and then need to divide into 4 part with 40 length.then each 40bytes then convert to shortArray then i need to decoded.. then need to send to websocket.
Can you some one help me to how to write this logic below is android logic which is decoding properly in android..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _decoder = opus_decoder_create(16000, 1, &error);
}
-(void)onGetData:(NSData *)getData{
    if(self.isSocketOpen){
        NSData *opus = [OpusConverter.shared decodeOpusData:getData];

        [self.fileHandler writeData:opus];
        self.filePath = [self getVoiceData];

        NSInteger len = [opus length];
        NSLog(@"123Data length===%ld",(long)len);
        Byte *byteData = (Byte*)malloc(len);
        memcpy(byteData, [opus bytes], len);
        NSData * audioData = [NSData dataWithBytes:byteData length:len ];
 ///////////SENDING START FRAME
        NSError *error;
        NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:@{@"type": @"START",
                                        @"data": @{
                                            @"appid": @13432495,
                                            @"appkey": @"sdfgdfgsdfgsdfsg",
                                            @"dev_pid": @15372,
                                            @"lm_id": @1235,
                                            @"cuid": @"cuid-1",
                                            @"format": @"pcm",
                                            @"sample": @16000
                                        }
                } options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
        NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [[WebSocketManager shared] sendDataToServer:jsonString];

        ////////SENDING AUDIO FRAME
        [[WebSocketManager shared] sendDataToServer:audioData];

        /////////SENDING FINISH FRAME
        NSData *finishjsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:@{@"type": @"FINISH"
        } options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
        NSString *finishJsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:finishjsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [[WebSocketManager shared] sendDataToServer:finishJsonString];
    }
-(NSData*)decodeOpusData:(NSData*)data
{
    int audioLength = (int)[data length];
    Byte *byteData = (Byte*)malloc(sizeof(Byte)*audioLength);
    memcpy(byteData, [data bytes], audioLength);
    short decodedBuffer[960];
    int nDecodedByte = sizeof(short) * [self decode:byteData length:audioLength output:decodedBuffer];
    NSData* PCMData = [NSData dataWithBytes:(Byte *)decodedBuffer length:nDecodedByte];
    return PCMData;
} 
-(void)playbutton{
    self.filePath = [self getVoiceData];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.filePath];
    NSData *wavDATA = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [AudioManager.shared playAudioData:wavDATA completionHandler:^(BOOL successfully) {
           NSLog(@"Playing");
   }];
```

}

Below logic is working fine in android..
Can you someone help to fix this issue
Below is Android code.

```
    BUFFER_LENGTH = 40
    public fun opusDataDecoder(data:ByteArray){
                  val tntOpusUtils = OpusUtils.getInstant()
                  val decoderHandler = tntOpusUtils.createDecoder(16000, 1)
                  for (i in 0..3){
                      val byteArray = ByteArray(BUFFER_LENGTH)
                      System.arraycopy(data,i * BUFFER_LENGTH,byteArray,0, BUFFER_LENGTH)
                      val decodeBufferArray = ShortArray(byteArray.size * 8)
                      val size = tntOpusUtils.decode(decoderHandler, byteArray, decodeBufferArray)
                      if (size > 0) {
                          val decodeArray = ShortArray(size)
                          System.arraycopy(decodeBufferArray, 0, decodeArray, 0, size)
                          opusDecode(decodeArray)//输出数据到接口
                      } else {
                          Log.e(TAG, "opusDecode error : $size")
                      }
                  }
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got solution for Decoding Audio data using OPUS library and converting PCM to WAV then play..

Below is updated working code..

## import "OpusAudioDecode.h"

```
@interface OpusAudioDecode : NSObject
+ (instancetype)shared;

-(void)opusInit;
-(NSMutableData*)decodeOpusData:(NSData*)data;
@end
```

## import "OpusAudioDecode.m"

```
#import "OpusAudioDecode.h"
#import "opus.h"

#define SAMPLE_RATE 16000
#define CHANNELS        1
#define WB_FRAME_SIZE 320

@implementation OpusAudioDecode
{
    OpusDecoder *decoder;
    int opus_num;
    int pcm_num;
}
+ (instancetype)shared {
    static id _instance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _instance = [[super allocWithZone: NULL] init];
    });
    return _instance;
}

+ (id)allocWithZone:(struct _NSZone *)zone {
    return [self shared];
}

- (id)copyWithZone:(struct _NSZone *)zone {
    return [[self class] shared];
}

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self opusInit];
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)opusInit
{
    int error;
    decoder = opus_decoder_create(SAMPLE_RATE, CHANNELS, &error);
    opus_decoder_ctl(decoder, OPUS_SET_SIGNAL(OPUS_SIGNAL_VOICE));
}

////int decode(unsigned char* in_data, int len, short* out_data, int* out_len) {
-(int)decode:(unsigned char *)encodedBytes length:(int)lengthOfBytes output:(short*)decoded {
     int frame_size = WB_FRAME_SIZE;
    unsigned char cbits[frame_size + 1];
     memcpy(cbits, encodedBytes, lengthOfBytes);
    pcm_num = opus_decode(decoder,cbits,lengthOfBytes,decoded,frame_size,0);
    return frame_size;
}

-(NSMutableData*)decodeOpusData:(NSData*)data
{
    NSMutableData *audioData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 4; i ++)
    {
        int bufferLength = 40;
        if([data length]>= 40){
        NSData *subData = [data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(i*bufferLength, bufferLength)];
        Byte *byteData = (Byte*)malloc(sizeof(Byte)*bufferLength);
        memcpy(byteData, [subData bytes], bufferLength);
        short decodedBuffer[WB_FRAME_SIZE];
        int nDecodedByte = sizeof(short) * [self decode:byteData length:bufferLength output:decodedBuffer];
        NSData *PCMData = [NSData dataWithBytes:(Byte *)decodedBuffer length:nDecodedByte ];
        [audioData appendData:PCMData];
        }
    }
    return audioData;
}
@end
```

**import"RecordingViewController.m"**

```
 #pragma mark - Reciving Audio Data from Deivce and DECODING with OPUS Library

-(void)recivedEncodedDatafromDevice:(NSData *)getData{
        NSMutableData *opus = [OpusAudioDecode.shared decodeOpusData:getData];
        [self.fileHandler writeData:opus];
}

#pragma mark - Save and Convert WAV From PCM

- (NSString *)getVoiceData{
    if (![CommonUtils isEmptyString:self.pcmPath]) {
        self.wavPath = [self createWavFromPcm:self.pcmPath];
    }
    return self.wavPath;
}

- (NSString *)createWavFromPcm:(NSString *)filePath {
    NSString *wavFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.wav", [filePath stringByDeletingPathExtension]];
    long totalAudioLen = 0;
    long totalDataLen = 0;
    long longSampleRate = 16000;
    int channels = 1;
    long byteRate = 16 * 16000 * channels/8;
    int numOfSamples = (int)[[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath] length];
    NSData * wavData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    if(numOfSamples>0){
    int wav1DataSize = (int)[[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath] length] - 44;
    NSData *Wave= [NSMutableData dataWithData:[wavData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(44, wav1DataSize)]];
    totalAudioLen=[Wave length];
    totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 44;
    Byte *header = (Byte*)malloc(44);
    header[0] = 'R';  // RIFF/WAVE header
    header[1] = 'I';
    header[2] = 'F';
    header[3] = 'F';
    header[4] = (Byte) (totalDataLen & 0xff);
    header[5] = (Byte) ((totalDataLen >> 8) & 0xff);
    header[6] = (Byte) ((totalDataLen >> 16) & 0xff);
    header[7] = (Byte) ((totalDataLen >> 24) & 0xff);
    header[8] = 'W';
    header[9] = 'A';
    header[10] = 'V';
    header[11] = 'E';
    header[12] = 'f';  // 'fmt ' chunk
    header[13] = 'm';
    header[14] = 't';
    header[15] = ' ';
    header[16] = 16;  // 4 bytes: size of 'fmt ' chunk
    header[17] = 0;
    header[18] = 0;
    header[19] = 0;
    header[20] = 1;  // format = 1
    header[21] = 0;
    header[22] = (Byte) channels;
    header[23] = 0;
    header[24] = (Byte) (longSampleRate & 0xff);
    header[25] = (Byte) ((longSampleRate >> 8) & 0xff);
    header[26] = (Byte) ((longSampleRate >> 16) & 0xff);
    header[27] = (Byte) ((longSampleRate >> 24) & 0xff);
    header[28] = (Byte) (byteRate & 0xff);
    header[29] = (Byte) ((byteRate >> 8) & 0xff);
    header[30] = (Byte) ((byteRate >> 16) & 0xff);
    header[31] = (Byte) ((byteRate >> 24) & 0xff);
    header[32] = (Byte) (2 * 8 / 8);  // block align
    header[33] = 0;
    header[34] = 16;  // bits per sample
    header[35] = 0;
    header[36] = 'd';
    header[37] = 'a';
    header[38] = 't';
    header[39] = 'a';
    header[40] = (Byte) (totalAudioLen & 0xff);
    header[41] = (Byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 8) & 0xff);
    header[42] = (Byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 16) & 0xff);
    header[43] = (Byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 24) & 0xff);

    NSData *headerData = [NSData dataWithBytes:header length:44];
    NSMutableData * soundFileData = [NSMutableData alloc];
    [soundFileData appendData:[headerData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 44)]];
    [soundFileData appendData:Wave];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:wavFilePath contents:soundFileData attributes:nil];
    }
    return wavFilePath;
}

#pragma mark - PLAYING DECODED DATA

-(void)playbutton{
    self.filePath = [self getVoiceData];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.filePath];
    NSData *wavDATA = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [AudioPlayerManager.shared playAudioData:wavDATA completionHandler:^(BOOL successfully) {
        NSLog(@"Playing");
    }];
}
```